# Two MultiDataTrigger for one button

Tags: wpf, binding, triggers, datatrigger

I have `MultiDataTrigger` looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="btnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseBtnStyle}">
    <Setter Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,2"/>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource GrayButtonTemplate}"/>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Num}" Value="1"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Str}"  Value="aaa"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

            <Setter Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The goal is that the button will be enabled as soon as str = aaa and Num = 1.

It works.

The problem is that I want the button will be enabled **even when Num = 2** (and str = aaa)

I tried to add more `MultiDataTrigger` after the first:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Num}" Value="2"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Str}"  Value="aaa"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

    <Setter Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="True" />
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

He did not refer to it, **the button is only enabled when Num = 1.**

There is another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest solution I can see is to create `IsEnabled` property in your object, where you have `Str` and `Num`

```
public bool IsEnabled
{
   get
   {
      return (Num == 1 || Num == 2) && Str == "aaa";
   }
}
```

bind `IsEnabled` in your `Style`

```
<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}"/>
```

and whenever `Str` or `Num` changes notify about `IsEnabled` change as well

Comment: What was the actual problem with the XAML in the question ? Is it not possible to have more than one MultiDataTrigger ? I am having a similar issue but creating a notifier property isn't really an option for me.

Comment: @Sherlock you can have as many `Triggers` as you like, in combinations you want (`Trigger`, `DataTrigger`, ...) and I don't know why in this particular case it did not work as in the my code, which does only that it works fine. This is just one way that allows you to create clean solution in `ViewModel` for when your condition is more complicated.

Comment: thanks for the response - I figured out my issue: for some reason moving my <MultiDataTrigger> elements from my control template to the <Style> worked. No idea why .. but this fixed it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a binding for IsEnabled property with converter,

```
    <Style x:Key="btnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseBtnStyle}">
        <Setter Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,2"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource GrayButtonTemplate}"/>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource myconverter}}"/>
    </Style>
```

Since we didn't specify the path for the Binding, entire data context object will pass through the converter. Based on several conditions, you can return true or false, that will enable or disable the button.

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var foo = (foo) value;
        return (foo.num == 1 || foo.num == 2) && foo.str == "aaa";
    }
```